# eliminating all values that occur in all files in folder with awk

Tags: awk

I have a folder with several files of which I want to eliminate all of the terms that they have in common using `awk`. 
Here is the script that I have been using:

```
awk '                
FNR==1 {
    if (seen[FILENAME]++) {
        firstPass = 0
        outfile = FILENAME "_new"
    }
    else {
        firstPass = 1
        numFiles++
        ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME
    }
}
firstPass { count[$2]++; next }
count[$2] != numFiles { print > outfile }
' *
```

An example of the information in the files would be:

File1

```
3   coffee  
4   and  
8   milk
```

File2

```
4   dog  
2   and  
9   cat
```

The output should be:

```
File1_new

    3   coffee   
    8   milk  

File2_new

    4   dog  
    9   cat
```

It works when I use a small number of files (i.e. 10), but when I start to increase that number, I get the following error message:

```
awk: file20_new makes too many open files  input record number 27, file file20_new  source line number 14
```

Where is the error coming from when I use larger amounts of files?

My main goal is to run this script over all of the files in a folder to generate new files that **do not** contain any words that occur in all of the files in the folder.

Comment: You need to `close()` your files when you are done with them. As is you carry every file you open around with you forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `>`, a file is opened for writing (and truncated). As suggested in the comments, you need to close your files as you go along. Try something like this:

```
awk '                
FNR==1 {
    if (seen[FILENAME]++) {
        firstPass = 0
        if (outfile) close(outfile) # <-- close the previous file
        outfile = FILENAME "_new"
    }
    else {
        firstPass = 1
        numFiles++
        ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME
    }
}
firstPass { count[$2]++; next }
count[$2] != numFiles { print > outfile }
' *
```

Comment: You can probably get away without the `if (outfile)`, it just seems cleaner.